# disabling selection style of primefaces datatable

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, selection

I use a checkbox datatable of primefaces and I want to disable style of selection (changing color of selected row) of datatable because I have some links in each row that are not propely displayed

How can I achieve that,

thanks

Comment: Please describe your problem with a sample.

Answer (score 5):

The selected row gets the css class "***ui-state-highlight***". You can override this class in your own css file to achieve your result. 
Firebug can provide big help here.

Comment: thank you, I found the appropriate class for hover it is : **ui-state-hover**, I tested to override it into style attibute of datatable but the hover style has not changed

Comment: there is someone who has any idea

Comment: what you need to override is the css class, not inline class in the datatable. Create your own css class **ui-state-hover** and choose the properties you need on it.

Answer (score 1):

In my datatable i changed this:

```
rowStyleClass="myownclass"
```

and in this way you can override the default class for datatable.